# Windows Toast Notification not showing in Action Center

Tags: windows, notifications

Need some help. I got this script working in power shell for toast notifications in Win 10 but the notification just wouldn't show in Action Center. Any help would be appreciated.

```
     param(
        [String] $Title
    )

    [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
    [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
    [Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument, Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null




$template = @"
    <toast duration = "long">
        <visual>
            <binding template="ToastGeneric">
                <text id="1">Hello World</text>
                <text id="2">How are you Today?</text>
                <text id="3">Can we Script something Great today?</text>
            </binding>
        </visual>
        <audio src="ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Reminder"/>
      </toast>
"@


    $xml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
    $xml.LoadXml($template)
    $toast = New-Object Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification $xml

    [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier("Visa Client Engineering").Show($toast)
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to create a registry key.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Visa Client Engineering`

Create a DWORD named `ShowInActionCenter` with value `1`.